# Static string variable with complex initialization in C#

Tags: c#, static-variables, lazy-initialization

I have a class with a static string variable that has a somewhat complex initialization (I can't just set it equal to a quoted string like `"whatever"`). I need to run a few lines of code to actually create the value. Once it gets set, its value won't change. It's currently set up as a property that just gets set on the first call to `get`.

```
class MyClass
{
    private static string _myString = "";
    public static string MyString
    {
        get
        {
            if(_myString == "")
            {
                // use an object "obj" here to create the value
                MyObject obj = new MyObject();
                obj.someSetupHere();
                _myString = obj.ToString();
            }
            return _myString;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: is there a better way to do this? I would rather the value be set up when all the other variables get set, rather than on the first "get" of the value. Should I be using a `Lazy<T>` here instead? I would really like something like:

```
private static string _myString = 
{
        // use an object "obj" here to create the value
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        obj.someSetupHere();
        _myString = obj.ToString();
}
```

I know that's probably not valid syntax, but hopefully it conveys what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just call a method:

```
private static readonly string _myString = GetMyStringValue();

private static string GetMyStringValue()
{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.someSetupHere();
    return obj.ToString();
}
```

You *could* do that all with a lambda expression cast to a `Func<string>` if you really wanted to avoid the extra declared method:

```
private static readonly string _myString = ((Func<string>) () =>
{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.someSetupHere();
    return obj.ToString();
}).Invoke();
```

Or use a static constructor to initialize the string:

```
private static readonly string _myString;

static MyClass()
{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.someSetupHere();
    _myString = obj.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Haha of course I could. Now I feel silly. Thank you!

Comment: Would using a static constructor be a valid alternative?

Comment: @cubrr: Yup, absolutely. Will add that.